# Unable to install npm truffle - WARN deprecated

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment, npm

I'm trying to set up npm truffle in the terminal in visual studio, but I got failure message saying npm WARN deprecated.

The command I use is npm install truffle -g
[image]

What should I do next? What updates do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry. This is not a failure message but just some warnings. If you get **errors**, something went wrong. Truffle will work just fine. You can verify that the installation was successful with

```
truffle --version
```